# Run a function on all parts of string php

Tags: php, arrays

I built a function which will capture text between brackets and output them as array. But the problem is that my function only executes first time in the string.

```
function GetBetween($content,$start,$end){ 
    $r = explode($start, $content); 

    if (isset($r[1])){ 
        $r = explode($end, $r[1]); 
        return $r[0]; 
    } 
    return ''; 
}

function srthhcdf($string){
    $innerCode = GetBetween($string, '[coupon]', '[/coupon]');
    $iat = explode('&&', $innerCode);
    $string = str_replace('[coupon]','',$string);
    $string = str_replace('[/coupon]','',$string);
    $newtext = '<b>'.$iat[0].'</b> <i>'.$iat[1].'</i><b>'.$iat[2].'</b>';
    $string = str_replace($innerCode,$newtext,$string);
    return $string;
}
$Text = srthhcdf($Text);
```

But it matches only first [coupon] and [/coupon] not others.
Like when the string is

```
hello world [coupon]hello && bad && world[/coupon] and also to [coupon] the && bad && world [/coupon]
```

It outputs

```
Hello world <b>hello </b> <i> bad </i><b> world</b> and also to the && bad && world.
```

Which means it replaces `[coupon]` and `[/coupon]` every time but doesn't formats the text inside them every time.

Comment: maybe a loop will help

Comment: can you provide en example string and result you expect?

Comment: but the text is retrived from mysql and its something like a wordpress post. So how many tiimes I should run the loop.

Comment: For single line its working fine i think provide some sample string

Comment: Edited the question for better explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check my solution. Your problem is, you are replacing the codes after the first call, and there is no loop:

```
function GetBetween($content, $start, $end) {
    $pieces = explode($start, $content);
    $inners = array();
    foreach ($pieces as $piece) {
        if (strpos($piece, $end) !== false) {
            $r = explode($end, $piece);
            $inners[] = $r[0];
        }
    }
    return $inners;
}

function srthhcdf($string) {
    $innerCodes = GetBetween($string, '[coupon]', '[/coupon]');
    $string = str_replace(array('[coupon]', '[/coupon]'), '', $string);
    foreach ($innerCodes as $innerCode) {
        $iat = explode('&&', $innerCode);
        $newtext = '<b>' . $iat[0] . '</b> <i>' . $iat[1] . '</i><b>' . $iat[2] . '</b>';
        $string = str_replace($innerCode, $newtext, $string);
    }
    return $string;
}

$testString = "hello world [coupon]hello && bad && world[/coupon] and also to [coupon] the && bad && world [/coupon]";
$Text = srthhcdf($testString);
echo $Text;
```

Comment: sorry to say but ; Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /srv/users/st/apps/cour/public/single.php on line 20

Comment: Works great. The best answer based on what the question is.

Comment: You are welcome, but check other answers too. preg_replace is more effective, and elegant. I've just want you to point to the right direction if you want to solve like this.

Comment: +[1] for suggestion. But I actually wanted to solve the thing this way.

Answer (score 1):

using Regex will be a easy solution for this kind of things

```
$Text = "hello world [coupon]hello && bad && world[/coupon] and also to [coupon] the && bad && world [/coupon]";

$result = preg_replace('%\[coupon]([^[]*)\[/coupon]%', '<i>\1</i>', $Text);

print $result;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code instead:

```
$Text = 'hello world [coupon]hello && bad && world[/coupon] and also to [coupon] the && bad && world [/coupon]';

echo preg_replace('#\[coupon\][\s]*(\w+)([\s&]+)(\w+)([\s&]+)(\w+)[\s]*\[\/coupon\]#i', '<b>$1</b> <i>$3</i><b>$5</b>', $Text);
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution with ReGex (will capture all text and [coupon][/coupon] and replace them with your new String

```
preg_replace('#\[coupon\][A-Z0-9]+\[/coupon\]#i', $replaceText, $content);
```

if you want to conserve your [coupon] tags :

```
preg_replace('#(\[coupon\])[A-Z0-9]+(\[/coupon\])#i', '$1'.$replaceText.'$2', $content);
```